# How to add live location tracking in Flutter even app is terminated?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps

I want to implement Google Map live location tracking to my application. For example  I have two users, one is a carrier and one is a customer. When customer want to see where is my cargo, my application will show carrier's location to customer even carrier's application closed. How can I make this logic? I already tried packages like Workmanager. My application will work IOS and Android both. Do I have to write native code for both? If so, I maybe can write for Android but I dont know IOS side. How popular applications like Whatsapp or Snapchat do that? Is it possible to do this in Flutter?

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look on the following package: https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator. It implemented your use-case by allowing background fetching of the position. It even handles the Foreground service on Android as far as I know.